# Amplification in multistage amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, analog, audio

I'm building a double stage Common Emitter preamp and I'm wondering about the order of amplification. I want a voltage gain of 30 coming out of the second stage; would it matter if I had x10 in the first stage and x3 in the second as opposed to x6 and x5?

Answer (score 2):

> would it matter if I had x10 in the first stage and x3 in the second as opposed to x6 and x5?

As far as total amplification goes, no, it would not matter.

However...

Multiple stages of amplification are often employed, not only to get a higher gain than from a single stage, but to give the combined amplifier the desired input and output impedances.

The input impedance should match the impedance of whatever transducer is feeding it. The output impedance should match the impedance of whatever the amplifier is driving.

When choosing how you wish to divide the work of amplification between your stages, you may wish to consider how to best achieve input and output impedance goals. You may even wish to consider using different amplifier configurations in each stage. CE, CC, and CB amplifiers all have different impedance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Like opamps, transistor's have what is effectively a gain-bandwidth product.  If both transistors are the same type, then making each stage have the same gain increases the available overall bandwidth.

OTOH

A common technique to meet seemingly conflicting goals, like low noise and high output current, is to combine two dissimilar amplifiers, one optimized for input noise (or harmonic distortion, or whatever) and one optimized for output strength.

Answer (score 1):

Av=30 is a good value to use for voltage gain with some modest reduction from input to output impedance.

Another method is to cascade both into a Darlington and use  Bias with Negative feedback, (NFB) with DC coupling.

The ratios of each value are less sensitive on hFE but more sensitive to Vcc on the Q point DC voltages.  Raising the Vcc voltage makes the fixed bias input R higher allows for more collector current which improves open-loop gain and thus linearity the NFB.

Bottom-line is you still need to define all the other amp. variables. Zin, Zout, linearity or symmetry, noise frequency response, noise and component tolerances to do a proper design.

[You can play with values here using the mouse wheel and with undo.](http://and%20more%20negative%20feedback%20improves%20linearity.)

[image]